# Storing the output of a function into a variable in R

Tags: r, while-loop, average, mean

I'm having trouble with storing the output of a function into a variable. I think it's best that I give some context to the problem I'm trying to work out.
Suppose that players "a" and "r" play a game of tennis, the runningScoreFn sums the pointHistory vector and puts everything together in a nice data.frame

```
runningScoreFn = function(pointHistory){
playerUni = c("a", "r")
cols = sapply(playerUni, function(thisPlayer){
cumsum(pointHistory == thisPlayer)
})
names(cols) = playerUni
cbind(pointHistory, as.data.frame(cols))
}
```

The oneEpxiermentGameFn that plays out a game of "a" v.s "r".The first player to win 4 points wins the game, but he must be ahead by at least 2 points. "r" has 60% chance of winning a point.

```
pRogerPoint = 0.6

oneExperimentGameFn = function(pRogerPoint){
game = c(rep("r",pRogerPoint * 100), rep("a", 100-pRogerPoint*100))
i = 4
keepGoing = TRUE
while(keepGoing){
whosePoint = sample(game, size=i, replace=TRUE)
if(sum(whosePoint=="r")-sum(whosePoint=="a")>=2){
success = TRUE
print(cbind(runningScoreFn(whosePoint),success=success))
keepGoing = FALSE
}else if(sum(whosePoint=="a")-sum(whosePoint=="r")>=2){
success = FALSE
print(cbind(runningScoreFn(whosePoint),success=success))
keepGoing = FALSE
}
i=i+1
}
}
```

pRogerGameFn shows the probability that Roger wins the game.

```
pRogerGameFn = function(pRogerPoint, NExperiments){
RogerGameFn = lapply(1:NExperiments,function(dummy){

ok=oneExperimentGameFn(pRogerPoint)
})}
```

Here I wish to store the output into the variable ok, but ok returns NULL. I think this has something to do with my oneExperimentGameFn.
I also tried ok = RogerGameFn, but ok also returns NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is nothing returning from the function `oneExperimentGameFn`. 
If there is a specific value you want returned, insert a `return(.)` command at the end of the function (or wherever else appropriate).

If you simply want to catch the print statements, you can use `capture.output(.)`:

```
 ok <- capture.output(oneExperimentGameFn(pRogerPoint))
```